# How can I include the jboss-client.jar present in the Wildfly bin/client folder to my maven project?

Tags: maven, jboss-wildfly-11

I have a maven project to which I have to add a external jar jboss-client.jar which is located in Jboss Wildfly 10 bin folder(bin/client). There is no version specified in the jar name.

When I add the jar manually in build path-it works fine.

However, since this is a maven project, I require a better way of doing this.

Note: The project works with only this jar and not other versions specified in pom.xml which I tried downloading.

Also, if I try to specify the external dependency in pom.xml, it asks for version of the dependency. However, I cannot specify the same as it is not mentioned in the jar.

My ultimate aim is to deploy this project in Jboss Wildfly 10.

Is there any other alternate way, I can add the jar?

Comment: What are you using from the JAR?

Answer (score 0):

Copy your `jar` to some other location and unzip/decompress it, then find `Manifest file`  located at `META-INF\MANIFEST.MF` path.

Open it in text editor and look for `Implementation-Version`.

It will give you the version.

[Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/versioning/spec/versioning2.html#wp89936)

Comment: Thanks , I tried the above method and run the same application. This time I got the below error:
**java.lang.Exception: trace
 at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:386) ~[artemis-core-client-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]**

However, when jar is added to build path , then I do not get this error. Any suggestion for this?

Comment: which version did it show? and can you post full stack trace by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56389656/edit) your question

Comment: org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1165) [spring-jms-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1158) [spring-jms-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1055) [spring-jms-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]`

Comment: The above stack is the complete one. Any ideas?

Comment: can you share screenshot image instead?

Comment: Ok, but from where can I upload? Is there any upload option here?

Comment: no take a screenshot and upload it on some image hosting site, for eg [imgur](https://imgur.com/upload)

Comment: Actually that is a bit difficult. Main lines are below
*** [enerContainer-1] org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client  : AMQ212052: Packet PACKET(SessionBindingQueryResponseMessage_V2)[type=-8, channelID=13, packetObject=SessionBindingQueryResponseMessage_V2, exists=true, queueNames=[jms.queue.testingQ], autoCreateJmsQueues=false] was answered out of sequence due to a previous server timeout and it's being ignored.org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:307) ~[artemis-core-client-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
[spring-jms-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

You can use maven to install third party library in local.
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Using below command you can install.

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=path-to-file/jboss-client.jar -DgroupId=org.jboss -DartifactId=jboss-client -Dversion=1.0

Comment: There is a GAV for this so there's not need to do this. You can use `org.wildfly:wildfly-client-all:10.1.0.Final` assuming WildFly 10 here.